# How can I display an MD5 Hash of a Wordpress users registration date?

Tags: php, wordpress, date, md5

Linking through from clients wordpress site so a shop, and the shop webmaster has asked us to generate a link which ends with an MD5 hash of the username, and user registration date.

E.g. www.linktoshop/?=USERNAMEMD5HASH-USERREGDATEMD5HASH/

I've tried two things, with similar success.

The below generates the username hash successfully, but then the md5hash of the date/time now, as opposed to registration date.

```
<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); $registered = ($user_info->user_registered . "\n");  echo md5($current_user->user_login) . "-" . md5(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($registered)));?>
```

And this code displays the MD5 has of the username, and displays the correct registration date - but i can't figure out how to MD5 hash it.

```
<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); echo md5($current_user->user_login); ?>-<?php $registered = ($user_info->user_registered . "\n"); echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($registered)); ?>
```

Thanks for any belp.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - posting in case it helps someone else!

```
<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); $registered = ($current_user->user_registered . "\n");  echo md5($current_user->user_login) . "-" . md5(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($registered))) ;?>
```